# How to revert Python3 upgraded code to original version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, migration, version, upgrade

I have converted my Python2.x code to Python3 version using futurize command (both stage1 and stage2 executed). But unfortunately, I didn't backup the code before migration.

Is there any way to revert back the changes done by futurize and get my original Python2.x code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`3to1`](https://pypi.org/project/3to2/) to convert Python3 code to Python2